# Typescript class property type based on a property value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible de let Typescript knows the type of a property based on the value of another one (if the other property has a limited number of values).

For example, I have a class like this:

```js
type AnimalType = 'dog' | 'cat' | 'fish';

class Animal {
    protected data: DogEntity | CatEntity | FishEntity;
    protected type: AnimalType;

    constructor(type: AnimalType, data: DogEntity | CatEntity | FishEntity) {
        this.type = type;
        this.data = data;
    }

    getAge() {
        switch(this.type) {
            case 'dog':
                // Here typescript knows that data is a DogEntity
                break;
            case 'cat':
                // Here typescript knows that data is a CatEntity
                break;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way for Typescript to know the type of `data` based on the value of `type`?
Something like:

- If `type` == `dog` then `data` is a `DogEntity`
- If `type` == `cat` then `data` is a `CatEntity`
- If `type` == `fish` then `data` is a `FishEntity`

Thanks!

Comment: Yuck. This looks like an anti-pattern and should be addressed with proper inheritance (which would also resolve the problem).

Comment: I guess I don't understand what advantages this has over actually using polymorphism.  Also it seems like this animal class is a [god object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) that is to say, why should a more generic type know about how/what subtypes should do?  Isn't that the point of subtypes?

Comment: Classes cannot directly implement discriminated unions.  You *could* make the class generic instead, but then your `switch`/`case` approach won't work without a type assertion.  That would look [like this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJV2lW).  But fighting against TS this way is not recommended; you should just have three subclasses and use a union of those, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wj07Ym).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: You are right guys. It was a mistake in the first place to not use proper inheritance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way for TypeScript to do this:

```js
type AnimalType = 'dog' | 'cat' | 'fish'

class Animal {
    data: DogEntity | CatEntity | FishEntity
    type: AnimalType

    // ... other code goes here
}

class Dog implements Animal {
    data: DogEntity
    type: 'dog' = 'dog'
}

// ... and so on for the other entity types
```

---

Another solution is to use assertions:

```js
class Animal {
    // ... same code as before

    isDog(animal: Animal): asserts animal.Data is DogEntity {
        return animal.type == 'dog'
    }

    // ... repeat for other entity types
}
```